# Append one by one in input text from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a `jQuery` script that appends all checkboxes values into one `<input type="text"/>` with `','`, but when I check one box, it appends all the values from the others checkboxes aswell, and I want only to append those I checked in sequence.

```js
$('.check_list').on('change', function() {
  var n = $(this).siblings('input:checkbox');
  var nControl = $('.codeParc');

  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    n.prop('checked', true);
    var vals = nControl.map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');

  } else {
    n.prop('checked', false);
  }
  $('#test').val(vals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" value="" class="check_list"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="2"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="3"></input>

<input type="text" id="test" value=""></input>
```

This code is returning me all values  `1,2,3` whenever I check one checkbox, what I need is to check one box and display only his number, and then append the rest when they are checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that `input` elements are self-closing, so its `<input />`, not `<input></input>`.

A simpler way to do this would be to map the selected values in to an array and update the text of the `input` with the values from that array each time a checkbox is clicked, something like this:

```js
$('.check_list').change(function() {
  $('.codeParc').prop('checked', this.checked);
  updateText();
});

$('.codeParc').change(function() {
  $('.check_list').prop('checked', $('.codeParc').length == $('.codeParc:checked').length);
  updateText();
});

function updateText() {
  var checkedValues = $('.codeParc:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  $('#test').val(checkedValues.join(','));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" value="" class="check_list" />
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="3" />
<input type="text" id="test" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want ?

```js
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
  // toggle all checkbox
  if($(this).hasClass('check_list')){
    $('.codeParc').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  }
  
  var vals = $('.codeParc:checked').map(function () {
       return $(this).val();
  }).get().join(',');
  $('#test').val(vals);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" value="" class="check_list"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="2"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="3"></input>

<input type="text" id="test" value=""></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want like this?

```js
$('.check_list').on('change', function () {
    var n = $(this).siblings('input:checkbox');
    var nControl = $('.codeParc');

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
       // n.prop('checked',true);
        var vals = nControl.map(function () {
            if($(this).prop('checked'))
            {
             return $(this).val();
            }
            else
            {
             return;
            }
        }).get().join(',');

    } else {
      //  n.prop('checked',false);
    }
    $('#test').val(vals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" value="" class="check_list"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="2"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="codeParc" value="3"></input>

<input type="text" id="test" value=""></input>
```